# NSObject Usage: Creating, Inheriting, and Modifying

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm pretty experienced with the syntax of Objective-C, but am lacking in how the object parts of it work (yes I know, it's not good). I would like to know a few things:

1. How to create an object.
2. How to make it inherit certain properties from other classes (i.e. UIView).
3. How to make your own properties inside them (i.e. Health, Damage, Stamina).

If someone can please help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is answered in its entirely by the basic language documentation provided by Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples to look at before reading the documentation already posted:
To instantiate a class:

```
SomeClass *instantOfSomeClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

To inherit properties you would subclass it. To add custom properties, specify them in your subclass.

```
@interface SomeClassThatExtendsUIView : UIView
@property NSInteger health;
@property NSInteger damage;
@property NSInteger stamina;
@end

@implementation SomeClassThatExtendsUIView
// if not using auto synthesize
@synthesize health = _health;
@synthesize damage = _damage;
@synthesize stamina = _stamina;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to create an object.**

An object is a concept of object oriented programming but practically speaking it can be defined as an instance of a class.

Depending on what kind of object you want, there are several ways to create it. However they can all be created with a simple alloc - init

Generally speaking it should be:

```
ClassName *objectName = [[ClassName alloc] init];
```

**How to make it inherit certain properties from other classes (i.e. UIView).**

They inherit the properties when you sub class them. For example:

```
@interface UIView : UIResponder
```

is a Subclass of UIResponder which is a subclass of NSObject:

```
@interface UIResponder : NSObject
```

if you wanted to make your own "object" with the properties of an UIView you would simply have to
do something like this:

```
@interface customView : UIView
```

on the header of *your custom class*.

xcode conveniently allows you to subclass by letting you pick the super class when you create a new class. If you do this it will even give you a template of the commonly override methods.

**How to make your own properties inside them (i.e. Health, Damage, Stamina).**

Once you have created your custom class as a subclass of whatever you want you just have to add your own properties in the header file:

customView.h :

```
@interface CustomViewClass : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *customButton;

- (void)someCustomMethod;

@end
```

Then when you want to use this you just have to

```
CustomViewClass *customView = [[CustomViewClass alloc] init];
```

and your custom view will have access to the usual UIView properties and the customButton property as well.

(The actual uiview class default constructor is the initWithFrame but you can also initialize it this way and set the frame later) 
Command click on any UIView declaration and you will see this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;          // default initializer
```

Hope this helps